# Timezone mismatch between SPARK SQL and Cassandra

Tags: datetime, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load data from Cassandra to Spark DataFrame, but timestamp column value is being converted to UTC time zone instead of EDT

I am looking for a solution where time zone should be EDT in both the cases.

for example:

**Cassandra timestamp :-** 16-08-2017 00:00:00 (EDT Time Zone)

**Obtained timestamp after querying spark sql dataframe/tempview:-** 15-08-2017 20:00:00 (4 hour variation and the time zone is UTC)

I googled a lot and found that conversion would be done based on the local timestamp, but even after changing the local timestamp I am still seeing that time zone is being modified with in the SPARK SQL

FYI:

Cassandra Time Zone: EDT
Local Time Zone where spark job is being run: EDT

Comment: Cassandra is using UTC time to store in timestamps column. If you need specific time zone instance in output, you should have to cast UTC to required time zone. There are way you can do it with generated column of dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra by default uses UTC time zone, but timezone specified in cqlshrc would only make a change/typecast while displaying it to the console.

For My case i had modified the local time zone from EDT to UTC to get the things done, but as specified it can also be caste to required time.

Thankyou @Uttam Kasundara for triggering the perfect point.